# How to return all values from a single table column using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, http, jpa

This is what I have tried:

```
public List<T> findByAttribute(String attribute) {
    Query query = getEntityManager().
        createQuery("SELECT c." + attribute + " FROM "entityClass.getName() + " c");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Then I am implementing the method:

```
@GET
@Path("emailCheck")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public List<customers> getEmail() {
    return super.findByAttribute("email");
}
```

I made sure it won't return an empty set. Netbeans also validated the JPA Query for syntax.

I am getting HTTP error 500 on request.

Comment: You get a HTTP 500 error. So what do the server side logs say?

Comment: Provide server logs, will be extremely useful in this problem investigation.